# Determining row of grid from templated checkbox selection with autopostback

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox, autopostback, oncheckedchanged

I have a databound grid with a templated field column that is a checkbox.  When the user checks the checkbox, it will autopostback and update the row to indicate the box's check state.

My first attempt was to simply use the OnCheckedChanged method, but when this gets called, I have no way to know which row the checkbox came from.  Thus, I don't know which row to update.

Can anyone suggest a method to determine which row the checkbox that fired the oncheckedchanged event came from?  Or can you suggest a better way to achieve what I need to do?

I cannot bind the checkbox to the data column because I do not want the checkbox disabled in select mode, and do not wish to require the user to enter edit mode to change the value.  I also need all rows to be editable.  So, the best route seems to be in a templated column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the checked Checkbox by iterating over the rows.

```
Protected Sub MyCheckBoxCheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("MyCheckBoxID"), CheckBox)
        If sender Is cb AndAlso cb.Checked Then
            'Do something ...'
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This isn't as inefficient as it looks like(when the Grid's PageSize is not too high).

You can also get the GridViewRow via Checkbox.Parent.Parent:

```
  Protected Sub MyCheckBoxCheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(cb.Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)
        row.BackColor = DirectCast(IIf(cb.Checked, Color.Red, Color.White), Color)
  End Sub
```

This is faster as option 1 but if you f.e. would nest the Checkbox in a Table in the future, this wouldn't work anymore without adjustment.

I would normally prefer option 1, because in an event-handler one millisecond more or less doesn't matter.

---

**Update**: getting the GridViewRow via [NamingContainer](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2007/02/25/Understanding-the-naming-container-hierarchy-of-ASP.NET-databound-controls.aspx) is another(in my opinion the best) option:

```
Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(cb.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
```

This even still works when you nest the Checkbox inside other Controls like a Table.

Comment: No, I do not want to find all the checked columns.  I want to know which checkbox was just checked, and only update that row.

Comment: Good idea about the Parent, Parent.. i'll give that a try tomorrow.  I agree with @jwiscarson that this seems hacky, though.  Your idea of checking if sender = found control seems a little inefficient, but that's a good idea as well.

Comment: I agree that cb.Parent.Parent look hacky and is actually not failsafe when you f.e. nest the Checkbox in another Control like a Table. Therefor control.NamingContainer is the best way to get the current GridViewRow from a Control. This is the way .Net is searching for Controls(f.e. FindControl).

Comment: After reading the documentation (I'd never used this property before), I agree with Tim -- NamingContainer should take care of this.

Comment: Excellent Idea, I completely forgot about NamingContainer.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  I'll test the code and report back.

Comment: You're welcome.
Btw, you're a little bit reserved to marking answers as useful, aren't you? (including  jwiscarson's answer) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this as stated without handling the `RowEditing`, `RowUpdating`, and `RowCancelingEdit` events.

Alternatively, I'd suggest adding a `CommandField` to the `GridView`, like so:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" />
```

You'll need to handle the GridView.SelectedIndexChanging, again like so:

```
    void GridView_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
    }
```

Once you're in `SelectedIndexChanging`, you can use `GridView.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].FindControl("id")` to get the control you need -- assuming this funcitonality is still critical to you.

**Edit:** I just read your update, and I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here. It sounds like you're familiar with the `CommandField`. What do you want your website to do when you check this checkbox that has to be done independently the row states?

**Edit 2:** You could also cast `object sender` to your `CheckBox`, and find the appropriate `GridRow` using `.Parent()`, but this has always felt extremely hacky to me.

**Edit 3:** I swear, I'm going to stop editing this eventually.

I've never tried this, but you could get a reference to `CheckBox.ClientID` and try going through each row in the GridView, and calling `GridViewRow.FindControl(CheckBox.ClientID)`. I really have no idea if this will work, though.

Comment: To answer your question as to what i'm trying to achieve... the checkbox indicates that certain data entities are "associated" with the current client.  Clicking the checkbox enables this association (which actually fires off a large number of sprocs to hook up all the appropriate data).  There can be several dozen to a few hundred of these checkboxes, so the client does not want to have to do "select row, enter edit mode, select checkbox, select update row" which is about 4 clicks and would be highly annoying.  They simply want clicking the checkbox to set the value.

Comment: Regarding your Edit 3, i'm not sure how finding the control is of any use, since sender is already a pointer to the control.  I don't think it's any easier to get the datarow using the control found via FindControl().

Comment: Err, sorry -- I was thinking about using it on a each of the Rows in the GridView, but didn't specify that correctly. Editing...